# ERROR AL COMPILAR UNA APLICACION MOVIL!

Tags: gradle, genexus

Trabajo con GX 16 U 11 tengo un problema con la compilacion de una app movil. Cuando doy compilar y build no me deja hacerlo solo me sale problemas con el gradle, no se por qué, GX  predefine la propiedad --no-daemon --parallel -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -Dorg.gradle.internal.launcher.welcomeMessageEnabled=false

Pero la verdad es que no se mucho del tema, ya he probado de todo, hasta pensar que era problema de mi KB pero hice una sencilla con solo un workwith de movil y sigue el mismo bateo. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser?Gracias de antemano.

El error que sale dice algo asi:

> Command: gradle :SDMenuSlide:assembleDebug --no-daemon --parallel
> -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -Dorg.gradle.internal.launcher.welcomeMessageEnabled=false To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please
> consider using the daemon:
> https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
>
> Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after
> processing error: error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> error: error: * What went wrong: error: A problem occurred configuring
> root project 'Android'. error: > Could not resolve all artifacts for
> configuration ':classpath'. error: > Could not download gradle.jar
> (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1) error: > Could not get resource
> 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar'.
> error: > Could not GET
> 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar'.
> error: > Permission denied: connect error: > Could not download
> builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.1) error: > Could not
> get resource
> 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.1/builder-3.4.1.jar'.
> error: > Could not GET
> ...........

Comment: Con “de urgencia” parece más una orden. Explica de mejor manera el error.

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas salida a internet o estés bajo algún Proxy? Por si es así, entonces parecería ser ese el problema.

Se precisa una dependencia de terceros, la cual debe descarga. Luego de esto, si quieres compilar sin internet puedes utilizar la flag "--offline" agregandola a la propiedad Gradle Options.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no tenes los requerimientos instalados para ejecutar correctamente en Android y al intentar bajar dependencias te da error porque no tiene salida a Internet.

Para instalar solamente lo que requiere genexus para ejecutar, debes ir dentro de IDE a:

tools > Update Android SDK

Esa opcion te levantara un wizard que te instala los requerimientos minimos necesarios para poder ejecutar.